# How to get different records based on multiple indicators

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working in SQL server 2014. My database consists of 2 tables. "DW" and "STG2". DW maintains a history of my data and STG table holds only the daily data that comes. The Structure of the DW table is like this: HID,Ticketnumber, ISS_IND. Structure of STG2 table is only HID. HID in both the tables are same and on this ID we can join them which I have shown in the query. This ISS_IND column of DW table can contain these values: F,I,U,R,W and Y.If a record contains F,I or U value then it is considered of same category which is named "Primeissue" and if the record contains R,W or Y then it is considered of same category which is Reissue. Below is table of DW:

```
HID     Ticketnumber      ISS_IND
1000    123               F
1000    123               I
1000    123               U
1001    456               F
1001    456               R
1001    456               I
```

Table of STG2:

```
 HID
 1000
 1001
```

Now we can notice that HID 1001 has different category F being primeissue and R being reissue. Now I want to get such type of records thorugh my query

For now I have just joined them and is unable to implement the primeissue and reissue logic so far.

```
select 
STG2_SBR_STTK_NWTST.HID,DW_SBR_STTK_NWTST.Ticketnumber
  ,DW_SBR_STTK_NWTST.IS_IND
 from DW_SBR_STTK_NWTST
JOIN STG2_SBR_STTK_NWTST ON STG2_SBR_STTK_NWTST.HID=DW_SBR_STTK_NWTST.HID
```

Output:

```
HID   Ticketnumber
1001   456
```

Any guidance on how I can get such records? Thank you.

Comment: what is your expected output - provider your expected output in table format

Comment: expected output

Comment: output can be just the IDs

Comment: 1 output please. there is 3 columns.

Comment: On a sidenote: The knowledge what category a status belongs to should not only be in your head, but also in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possible approach (based on your statement) is to use SUM() function for calculation and get the rows with sum greater than 0 for each category:

```
-- Tables
CREATE TABLE #DW_SBR_STTK_NWTST (
    HID int,
    Ticketnumber int, 
    ISS_IND varchar(1)
)
CREATE TABLE #STG2_SBR_STTK_NWTST
(
    HID int
)
INSERT INTO #DW_SBR_STTK_NWTST
    (HID, Ticketnumber, ISS_IND)
VALUES
    (1000, 123, 'F'),
    (1000, 123, 'I'),
    (1000, 123, 'U'),
    (1001, 456, 'F'),
    (1001, 456, 'R'),
    (1001, 456, 'I')
INSERT INTO #STG2_SBR_STTK_NWTST
    (HID)
VALUES
    (1000),
    (1001)

-- Statement
SELECT 
    #STG2_SBR_STTK_NWTST.HID,
    #DW_SBR_STTK_NWTST.Ticketnumber
FROM #DW_SBR_STTK_NWTST
JOIN #STG2_SBR_STTK_NWTST ON (#STG2_SBR_STTK_NWTST.HID = #DW_SBR_STTK_NWTST.HID)
GROUP BY #STG2_SBR_STTK_NWTST.HID, #DW_SBR_STTK_NWTST.Ticketnumber
HAVING 
    (SUM(CASE WHEN #DW_SBR_STTK_NWTST.ISS_IND IN ('F', 'I', 'U') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0) AND
    (SUM(CASE WHEN #DW_SBR_STTK_NWTST.ISS_IND IN ('R', 'W', 'Y') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0)
```

Output:

```
HID     Ticketnumber
1001    456
```

Comment: A mere comment under my answer that `count(when .. then 1 end)` can also be written as `sum(when .. then 1 else 0 end)` would have sufficed (which I actually had done myself already when you posted your answer). Why do you join with table `STG2_SBR_STTK_NWTST`? It seems superfluous.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner  This answer is based on statement in the question, so I've used it as it is. I use `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()`, not just here, because I can include weight factor when selecting records - something like `CASE WHEN ISS_IND = 'F' THEN 2 WHERE ISS_IND = 'R' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`.
Of course, using COUNT() here is correct. Thanks for this comment, this answer is just another possible approach.

Answer (score 2):

Group by `HID` and use the `HAVING` clause to check whether it has both categories.

```
select hid
from dw
group by hid
having count(case when iss_ind in ('F', 'I', 'U') then 1 end) > 0
   and count(case when iss_ind in ('R', 'W') then 1 end) > 0
order by hid;
```

Comment: why you have used the count here? can you explain it a bit....thank you.

Comment: You want one result row per `HID`. So you aggregate and group by `HID`. You want to keep those `HID` the number of entries for both categories of which is greater than zero. So count. The case expression results in 1 when the condition is met, null otherwise. `COUNT` only counts non-null expressions. So we count the matched criteria. An alternative way to do this would be  with `SUM`: `sum(case when iss_ind in ('F', 'I', 'U') then 1 else 0 end) > 0`.